# How to know if user shared my app or not?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

My app is all about getting points and winning money, and what I need to do is let the user share my app then give him some points.

The problem is that I don't know how to detect if the user truly shared the app or not

I'm using the following code:

```
func shareTapped(){
    let text = "example"
    let url = URL(string: "example.com")
    let image = UIImage(named: "example_image")
    let shareViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text, image!, url!] ,applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(shareViewController, animated: true, completion: {() in
        print("done")
    })
}
```

The sharing method is working perfectly, but I was wondering if there is any delegate we can call in this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: did you check if `self.presentedViewController == shareViewController ` is `false`?

Comment: It's not clear for me, can you explain more please @azinwi

Comment: I think @Dharmesh's answer is what you need?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So there is 2 scenarios where user can cancel share.

One is when `UIActivityViewController` present then there is a cancel button on `UIActivityViewController` from where user can cancel it and yes you can detect it with method

```
shareViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, completed, items, error in

}
```

In above method `completed` will be `false` if user canceled from `UIActivityViewController` cancel button. and it will return `true` if user share successfully but here comes second case with it.

So for second case suppose user want to share via watsapp and click on watsapp icon from  `UIActivityViewController` and watsapp user list appear.

But there is a cancel button on that screen from where user can cancel sharing but still you will get `completed` flag `true` so there is no way you can detect if user click on `cancel` button from watsapp user list.

Comment: happy to help..:)